# css child selector

Tags: css

I have this list :

```
   <ul class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <li><a href="#"><span>community</span> </a>
        <ul class="level1">
            <li><a href="#"><span>Commun1</span> </a>
                <ul class="level1">
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Events</span></a>
        <ul class="level1">
            <li><a href="#"><span>Event1</span> </a>
                <ul class="level1">
                <li><a href="#"><span>Event2</span></a>
                <ul class="level1"></ul>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li> the the first ul under community and the first ul under Events
</ul>
```

I need to access only the first ul with the class level1  Im using  In each ul I need to access only

```
            .topnav li > ul 
             {
              //code here
             }
```

I've updated my code still can't access the only the fi

Comment: your html is seriously messed up - is this a product of view source?

Comment: Is #topnav >  li:first-child > ul what you're after? I can't tell if you want the first ul with .level1 (and have it happen once) or if you want the first ul with .level1 that's inside a ul (and have it happen multiple times)

Comment: I want to have it happen multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this:

```
#topnav li:first-child ul
{
    // your style
}
```

See the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/bqBdn/4/

Note: Your HTML code is little bit buggy, So correct it as I did in this demo. Use proper tagging for `ul, li` inside main `li`Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it works for me: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SuperPhil/bqBdn/)

```
ul.topnav li > ul {
   color:blue;
}
```

Comment: it's applying the style on all the ul.I need to apply it only on the firdt ul and I can't change the class im obliges with this code.

Comment: add `<li/>`'s to the other `<ul />`'s and you'll see it doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/lnrb0b/bqBdn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#topnav li ul:first-child
```

from [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
.topnav li > ul.level:first-child
```

will access only the first ul with a .level class at the first level after the li.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your html is wrong. You can't have an `<li />` as a child of another `<li />`. The browser is correcting the mistake - bringing all the `<ul />`'s under the initial one to the same level. Your css is working, your html is the problem.

Are you able to change this?